# RealmIOException: Failed to access: . make_dir() failed

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform

I get this issue when I installed app from MDM(Mobile iron) where application will be wrapped for security purpose.
But it works fine if I install from Android studio,
Can any one please give solution ?

Ream : 1.0.1
minSDK: 18
Stack trace:

```
  Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{forgepond.default.test/com.default.SplashActivity}:
io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException:
 Failed to access: . make_dir() failed: No such file or directory path: /data/user/0/com.default.test/files/default.realm.management
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5794)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException: Failed to access: . make_dir() failed: No such file or directory path: /data/user/0/com.default.test/files/default.realm.management
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.createNativeWithImplicitTransactions(Native Method)
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.openSharedGroupOrFail(SharedGroup.java:95)
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.(SharedGroup.java:74)
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroupManager.(SharedGroupManager.java:49)
at io.realm.BaseRealm.(BaseRealm.java:81)
at io.realm.Realm.(Realm.java:139)
at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:250)
at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:230)
at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:126)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

As we wrapped using Gen1 wrapper technology which has no external storage access permission is the issue. When we tried with Gen2 wrapper it works fine.